# PostMessage from a thread

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, vcl

My VCL application register two messages in WinMain

```
    unsigned int WM_CAMERA_STOPPED_RECORDING;
    unsigned int WM_CAMERA_STARTED_RECORDING;

    int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int)
    {...
         WM_CAMERA_STOPPED_RECORDING = RegisterWindowMessage(L"CameraStoppedRecording");
         WM_CAMERA_STARTED_RECORDING = RegisterWindowMessage(L"CameraStartedRecording");
```

A thread is Posting the message when appropriate:

```
        int ret = PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_CAMERA_STARTED_RECORDING, 0, 0);
```

My mainForm has a over ridden WindPRoc:

```
void __fastcall TMainForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    if(Message.Msg == WM_CAMERA_STOPPED_RECORDING && WM_CAMERA_STOPPED_RECORDING > 0)
    {
        UIFrame->FocusZoneFrame->onCameraFinishedRecording();
    }

    else if(Message.Msg == WM_CAMERA_STARTED_RECORDING && WM_CAMERA_STARTED_RECORDING > 0)
    {
        UIFrame->FocusZoneFrame->onCameraStartedRecording();
    }

    TForm::WndProc(Message);
}
```

Question is, is there a difference in using the *PostMessage* function in a thread vs in the main thread?

I'm asking cause I'm getting some unstable behavior in the application where the main UI thread get blocked somewhere and wonder if it can be related to how PostMessage is used above.

Comment: no different. but are you really need `HWND_BROADCAST` ? why you not pass to worked thread your concrete `hwnd` and post message direct to it ? and are you really need `RegisterWindowMessage` instead use from `WM_APP` + range ?

Comment: There is no difference. Posted messages are placed in the receiving thread's message queue. Queued messages are dispatched on the thread the owns the message queue.

Comment: Do note that there is a very small window of opportunity for `TMainForm` to not receive posted messages, if `PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST)` happens to be called while `TMainForm` is in progress of re-creating its `HWND`. I would suggest using `AllocateHWnd()` instead so you have a persistent `HWND` to receive all of the posted messages with.